# Issue when apply RIB and Autodispose libs

Tags: autodispose

I have problem when apply Rib (ver 0.9.1) and `Autodispose` (ver 1.1.0) libs. My `RootActivity` (`extent RibActivity`) cannot resolve "`LifecycleScopeProvider`". I found that `LifecycleScopeProvider` not exist in ver 1.1.0 but have in ver 0.2.0.

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0):

RIBs are not maintained publicly are are using an old version of the library. You'd need to use the modern names for those items post-1.0.